# Disable maximizing in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

So I have an electron app. I have set maxWidths and maxHeights but how do I disable maximizing.

I have already made custom buttons for ms-windows but i don't want to remove the traffic lights on mac.

On other applications, i have seen the green traffic light greyed out. How do I acheive this?

Comment: do you want a fixed size window?

Comment: No, my app just isn't sutable for full screen.

Answer (score 4):

This is supported by Electron out of the box. When creating your `BrowserWindow` just set the `maximizable` property of the options object to `false`. Since you didn't show us any code, this is just an example:

```js
const { BrowserWindow } = require ("electron");
var window = new BrowserWindow ({ title: "My App", maximizable: false });
```

Please note that at the time of writing, this is not supported on Linux. See the [Electron documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#new-browserwindowoptions) for more information on `BrowserWindow` and its options.

Answer (score 1):

See https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window

```
resizable boolean (optional) - Whether window is resizable. Default is true.
```

Answer (score 0):

In windows machine, Browser Window can be restricted to maximize by putting option `maximizable: false`. See code example below.

```
const { BrowserWindow } = require ("electron");
var window = new BrowserWindow ({ title: "My App", maximizable: false });
```

Comment: Might you please [edit] your code-only answer to give some explanation?  The question asks to disable **maximizing** in electron, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68334957/3744182) by Alexander Leithner suggests `new BrowserWindow ({ title: "My App", maximizable: false });`  Why would `minimizable: false` be preferable? -[From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/33424629)