# How can i disable the Maximize button for BrowserWindow in Electron?

Tags: javascript, npm, electron

Im new to Electron.js and im trying to disable the Maximize button, i know its possible but i don't know how to do it.

I tried `frame: false` but its not working

My code if it helps:

```js
const win = new BrowserWindow({
    autoHideMenuBar: false,
    width: 700,
    height: 830,
    resizable: false,
    titleBarStyle: 'hidden',
    titleBarOverlay: {
      color: '#2f3241',
      symbolColor: '#e2c890'
    },
    frame: false,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable maximizing in electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68326717/disable-maximizing-in-electron)